# Run Java Client on VMware Virtual Machine

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client-server Java project, from which I have generated a JAR file for the client execution. 
When the JAR file is not running on Vmware, it easily connects to the server (which is running in IntelliJ).
However, it cannot connect to the server when it is on the virtual machine. 
It gives me this error:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

Has anyone had any similar experience?

Comment: Have you checked that the port you're connecting to is open and in use by the application?

Comment: @libanbn Yes, and Actually I can ping the InetAddress of the Server, from the VMware, too. 
But still, it does not get connected...

Comment: If the project works locally and the server IP is working, then it's most likely that the firewall is blocking the communication on the port.